# Hyperledger Fabric: TLS handshake failed with error tls

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, tls1.2

I have set up a network with raft ordering service (5 orderers), 2 orgs and one peer each, the TLS and client authentication are both enabled. I have created the channel and joined it successfully, but I am getting TLS handshake failed error when updating the anchor peer from cli to orderer, and I am not able to create a second channel for the same error. Besides this TLS error why I was able to create the first channel I am very confused, surely incorrect configs causing that.

CLI Commands:

```
export ORDERER_CA=crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/tlsca/ca-chain.pem
export CLIENT_KEY_FILE=crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.key
export CLIENT_CERT_FILE=crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.pem

*Worked: peer channel create -o orderer0.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA --clientauth --keyfile $CLIENT_KEY_FILE --certfile $CLIENT_CERT_FILE

*Worked: peer channel join -b muchannel.block

*FAILED: peer channel update -o orderer0.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/anchors_channel.tx --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA --clientauth --keyfile $CLIENT_KEY_FILE --certfile $CLIENT_CERT_FILE
```

CLI  yaml config:

```
- CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
- CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.pem
- CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
- CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/ca-chain.pem 
- CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED=true
- CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE=crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.pem 
- CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTKEY_FILE=crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.key
```

Orderer yaml config:

```
- ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
- ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer0.example.com/tls/server.key 
- ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer0.example.com/tls/server.pem
- ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/tls/ca-chain.pem] 
- ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED=true
- ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS=[crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/tlsca/ca-chain.pem,crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/ca-chain.pem,crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/tlsca/ca-chain.pem]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command with following environment in your CLI container:

```
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=orderer.example.com:7050
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export ORDERER_CA=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel
```

This is because issuing channel update transaction requires updating the channel configuration file, which according to your present policies, must be signed by an Orderer Organization admin.

Comment: Hi, that did not work. Orderer gave me error: "TLS handshake failed with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress", CLI showed "Error: Error getting broadcast client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer0.example.com:7050"

Comment: What my intention of the answer is that you must update the channel using the Admin credentials of the orderer organization.

Comment: I used the orderer admin to run the update and it still failed, I used peer admin to run the channel create, do I need to use orderer admin to create the channel?

Comment: Which organization's anchor peers are you trying to update? You need to submit the transaction on behalf of that organization admin. You can check `./byfn.sh` script in the `first-network` deployment of `fabric-samples`.

Comment: Org1 peer, I created the channel and joined it (without TLS issue), then update the channel and it failed with TLS handshake issue, it is mentioned above in my CLI commands section.

Comment: Try running with TLS flag set to true: `peer channel update -o orderer0.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/anchors_channel.tx --tls true --cafile $ORDERER_CA --clientauth --keyfile $CLIENT_KEY_FILE --certfile $CLIENT_CERT_FILE`